# Repeating an auxiliary verb like "was" after "and" for a passive tense?

Tags: grammar

Should I repeat an auxiliary verb like "was" after "and" for a passive tense?

Here's an example:

It **was shipped** to laboratory in maximum time of one hour **and was frozen** at –80°C.

Comment: You can if you want to. It makes it clearer, but clarity is not everything. Note that the sentence has several article mistakes; _laboratory_ needs an article, and so does _maximum time_

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score -2):

The **was shipped** could easily be changed to **shipped**, they are both acceptable. The **and was frozen at -80°C** however should always have the **was** as without it, **and froze at -80°C** sounds more like a scientific observation of the freezing point than a statement of action.

It is perfectly fine to repeat "and" and "was", especially when they are this separated. If it was something more list-like, such as **it was made, packed and shipped** then in that situation, repeating "and was" sounds awkward. This is for the same reason repeating "and" in a list sounds awkward, though it is not necessarily wrong

Most of this is my opinion, this topic is kind of subjective. I am sure you could find something to this effect in a style guide, but I should be programing right now so I'm not going to go looking for one. ;)